# How to find the determinant this unknown sized matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I've got a matrix $A$ with a size of $(n \times n)$, that can be described like this:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n \\ 
-1 & 0 & 3 & \cdots & n \\ 
-1 & -2 & 0 & \cdots & n \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
-1 & -2 & -3 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How would I go about and find the determinant of this matrix (I thought about describing it as a sum but I don't know how to create an equation for any element $a_(ij_)$)?

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not a native English speaker so the solution might be really simple but I just don't know how to Google it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421863/how-to-calculate-this-n-by-n-determinant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try adding the first row to each of the other rows. That doesn't change the determinant and gives you an upper-triangular matrix.

Comment: "Upper-triangular matrix" is something everyone needs to know about, really makes things simpler. Thanks a lot!